# Load data from CSV using DataLoader

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have a `.csv` file with the following format:

```
x1, x2, y, x3, x4
05  05  0  00  12
01  09  1  00  17
       ...
13  24  0  01  00
```

I have created the following class that will help me load my data with a `DataLoader`, so as to shuffle it and read it in batches as well as apply any possible transformations that I might want to (e.g. Normalize) with the end goal of creating a simple RNN.

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):    
    def __init__(self, csv_file, transform=None):
        self.data_frame = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data_frame)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        m_data = self.data_frame.iloc[idx, :].as_matrix()
        m_data = m_data.astype('float')
        sample = {'y': np.array([m_data[2]]), 'x': np.delete(m_data, 2)}

        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        return sample
```

I can then load my data with something like

```
dataset = MyDataset(csv_file=file, transform=transforms.Compose([ToTensor()]))    
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
```

This follows [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html) tutorial from PyTorch, that it is for loading a data set of images.

My question is, since I have a completely different data set is what I am doing sensible for my case, or is there some other way I should load and preprocesor my data more efficiently?

Comment: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html Does this help you?

Comment: @keineahnung2345 this is the exact same page I have linked in my question, thanks for the suggestion regardless.